# Resampling date changes

Tags: resampling

I have resampled 10min frequency data for EURUSD forex pair from January 1st 2017 to October 6th 2018 using the resample function in python. But the resampled data is giving me data points until December 7th of 2018 which is wrong.

I am not sure why the dates are getting changed after resampling. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

This is my code and the last 5lines of the resampled data.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Vidya\Desktop\EURUSD_1_BID_01.01.2017-06.10.2018.csv")
df['Local time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Local time'], errors='coerce')
df.set_index(['Local time'],drop=True,inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df1 = df.tz_localize('UTC')
df2 = df1.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
df3 = df2.resample('10min').mean()
df3.isnull().any().any()
df4 = df3.fillna(method='ffill')
df4.isnull().any().any()
df4.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Vidya\Desktop\USDJPY10min311216-60918.csv')


                            Open     Close       Volume
Local time                                                
2018-12-07 14:10:00-05:00  112.6052  112.6080  58851.00001
2018-12-07 14:20:00-05:00  112.6344  112.6367  45211.00017
2018-12-07 14:30:00-05:00  112.6513  112.6526  68923.00004
2018-12-07 14:40:00-05:00  112.6672  112.6675  86051.00021
2018-12-07 14:50:00-05:00  112.6543  112.6526  76246.00085
```